# How can I check if 'Addtags' function works properly in Marekting cloud mobilepush SDK?

Tags: mobile, mobilepush, sdk, push

I'm in now process of configuring Mobilepush SDK in Marketing cloud, and we're currently using 'Addtags/Removetags' function to verify the login status of contacts. Here are the URL regardging this function.
https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/user-data.html

It might be too basic question, but I still have no idea about how to check if the tags have been added properly in Marketing cloud UI. Should I customize the 'Tags' attribute in data designer attribute group and is that it? Or Is 'tags' tab built-in feature in Mareking cloud? Then where shoud I find it? I tried to get answer from chat GPT but the answer was not enough to handle my curiosity. Since there are few information regarding this function, it would be huge help if anyone share your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags (and Attributes) are `MobilePush Demographics` and can be seen in Contacts.

I don't know your implementation, but you might consider using a single `Attribute` for something like `userState` and then `set` the value for logged in/out accordingly, but tags can certainly work. Just be careful to accurately add/remove them.

ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html